# Google chrome showing black edges when playing video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added a video background, everything works except that Google Chrome and Firefox are showing black edges when I'm playing the video (see image). When I ran the page on Edge and internet explorer the edges did not appear.

EDIT: I know the black edges are because I put the container as a black background but I dont want the container to show up in the edges. I just need the video to show up in full width

[image]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Resive video
    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
        
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        scaleVideoContainer();
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
    });

});

/** Reusable Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){
    
    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        videoWidth,
        videoHeight;
    
    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
            windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

        if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
            videoWidth = windowWidth;
            videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
        } else {
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
        }

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');
        

    });
}
```

```css
.homepage-hero-module {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
  display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
  display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.video-container .title-container {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .description .inner {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container .link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1001;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="intro" class="parallax-section">
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="title-container">
            <div class="headline">
                 <h1>Welcome to our Company</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay class="fillWidth">
            <source src="http://video.blendertestbuilds.de/download.blender.org/peach/trailer_480p.mov" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop muted />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
           <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm"  autoplay loop muted />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
            </video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content">
    <!-- adding this soon -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: first add video background with `position:fixed` .. then add text by using `position:absolute;`

Comment: You might have `padding` in the container class... remove the padding and it must be fine

Comment: The `.video-container` `div` is set to `width:100%` and has a `background-color` of `black`. Seems to me like that's exactly what you're seeing. When you say "but I dont want the container to show up in the edges," what exactly do you mean? Do you want to make the container smaller so it doesn't cover the full width of the page? Or maybe you want to make its background transparent so you see whatever's behind it? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not specify that. I just want the video on the full width of the page, the container is just there in case. Normally the video should cover the container though.

Comment: Even when I delete the container background, the video still does not show up in full width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `object-fit` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to control how the video is sized within its element.

If you want to stretch the video to exactly fill the entire element (like an `img` does by default), use:

```
object-fit: fill;
```

If you want to maintain the existing aspect ratio, and don't mind cropping the top and bottom, use:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Resive video
    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
        
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        scaleVideoContainer();
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
    });

});

/** Reusable Functions **/
/********************************************************************/

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){
    
    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        videoWidth,
        videoHeight;
    
    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width'),
            windowAspectRatio = windowHeight/windowWidth;

        if (videoAspectRatio > windowAspectRatio) {
            videoWidth = windowWidth;
            videoHeight = videoWidth * videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'top' : -(videoHeight - windowHeight) / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left' : 0});
        } else {
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});
        }

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');
        

    });
}
```

```css
.homepage-hero-module {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
  display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
  display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.video-container .title-container {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .description .inner {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container .link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1001;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="intro" class="parallax-section">
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="title-container">
            <div class="headline">
                 <h1>Welcome to our Company</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay class="fillWidth">
            <source src="http://video.blendertestbuilds.de/download.blender.org/peach/trailer_480p.mov" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop muted />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
           <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm"  autoplay loop muted />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
            </video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content">
    <!-- adding this soon -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I was trying to fix this for ages, thank you sir.

Comment: @Bart pointed out to me that `object-fit` doesn't work in Internet Explorer/Edge. It looks like [Microsoft has decided to implement it eventually](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition), but I imagine that's little consolation. There needs to be a different solution that works for those users.

Comment: Ok, I found out how to fix it, it's pretty easy actually. Just change the container color to the same color as your background so the container doesn't cover up the background.